# How to customize X-axis in react google chart

Tags: react-google-charts

I was trying to limit the horizontal axis to only two points ( minimum and maximum ).

I have tried using tick property for haxis but it seems to be not working for me.

here is the code snippet I have tried.

Please help

```
const chartoptions = {
  //hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
  hAxis: {textPosition: 'none',ticks: [-1000, -500, 0, 500, 1000], title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Amount'},
```

Comment: Can you include how you're applying the options to your chart? The definition looks correct.